I'm experiencing an issue with visionOS where 3D shapes are not consistently rendered correctly
Problem description:

In certain camera angles, shapes that should be occluded by objects in front of them are incorrectly rendered on top.
This creates visual artifacts where background objects appear in front of foreground objects.

Example:

In this example, the darker triangle should be completely hidden behind the lighter triangles, as its z-position is further back. However, it's incorrectly rendered on top.
Environment:

visionOS 2.0 Simulator

Code:
import SwiftUI

/// A shape view that draws itself as a right, isoscolese triangle.
struct Triangle: Shape {
    let vertex1: CGPoint
    let vertex2: CGPoint
    let vertex3: CGPoint

    init(_ point1: CGPoint, _ point2: CGPoint, _ point3: CGPoint) {
        vertex1 = point1
        vertex2 = point2
        vertex3 = point3
    }

    func path(in bounds: CGRect) -> Path {
        /// The drawing path for the triangle shape.
        var path = Path()

        // Start at the first vertex.
        path.move(to: vertex1)

        // Draw the triangle's first two sides.
        path.addLine(to: vertex2)
        path.addLine(to: vertex3)
        
        // Draw the triangle's third side by returning to the first vertex.
        path.closeSubpath()

        return path
    }
}


 ZStack {
                // MARK: 1
                Triangle(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                         CGPoint(x: 0, y: shapeScale / 2),
                         CGPoint(x: shapeScale / 2, y: shapeScale / 2))
                .animatableColor(getColor(for: 1))
                .frame(width: shapeScale, height: shapeScale)
                .animatableTransform3D(getTransform(for: 1))
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: step1 ? 180 : 0),
                                  axis: (x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
                                  anchor: .center)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: durationFold), value: step1)
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: step3 ? 165 : 0),
                                  axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0.0),
                                  anchor: .center)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: durationFold), value: step3)
                
                // MARK: 2
                Triangle(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
                         CGPoint(x: shapeScale / 2, y: 0),
                         CGPoint(x: shapeScale / 2, y: shapeScale / 2))
                .animatableColor(getColor(for: 2))
                .frame(width: shapeScale, height: shapeScale)
                .animatableTransform3D(getTransform(for: 2))
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: step3 ? 165 : 0),
                                  axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0.0),
                                  anchor: .center)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: durationFold), value: step3)
                
                // MARK: 3
                Triangle(CGPoint(x: shapeScale / 2, y: 0),
                         CGPoint(x: shapeScale / 2, y: shapeScale / 2),
                         CGPoint(x: shapeScale, y: shapeScale / 2))
                .animatableColor(getColor(for: 3))
                .frame(width: shapeScale, height: shapeScale)
                
                // MARK: 4
                Triangle(CGPoint(x: shapeScale / 2, y: 0),
                         CGPoint(x: shapeScale, y: 0),
                         CGPoint(x: shapeScale, y: shapeScale / 2))
                .animatableColor(getColor(for: 4))
                .frame(width: shapeScale, height: shapeScale)
                .animatableTransform3D(getTransform(for: 4))
                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: step2 ? -180 : 0),
                                  axis: (x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
                                  anchor: UnitPoint3D(x: 0.75, y: 0.25, z: 1))
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: durationFold), value: step2)

                .... 

Questions:

Is this a known issue in visionOS simulator? Note that I currently don't have access to a physical Vision Pro device to test this on real hardware - my observations are based on the simulator.
Are there any workarounds or best practices to ensure correct depth rendering?
Could this be related to z-fighting, and if so, how can it be mitigated in visionOS?


SwiftUI is inherently 2D you bridge to 3D with RealityView or Model3D
